# disable mouse when screen lock is enabled

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to disable my mouse every time I lock my screen.

this is the code which is my .xinitrc file:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOCKER='slock'
if [ $LOCKER -eq 1 ]; then
    exec xinput --set-prop 8 "Device Enabled" 0
else
    exec xinput --set-prop 8 "Device Enabled" 1
fi &
```

needless to say that I've already googled it a lot. I think what I miss here is where to put the script, but not the syntax itself.

Comment: Can you explain the goal of the `if` check there?

Comment: what screensaver/locker are you using?

Comment: I've never used `slock` but I can see that as written, the `if` test will always fail, and with an "expression expected" message.  Try this: `LOCKER=\`slock\`` (using backticks, not single quotes) or `LOCKER=$(slock)`.

Comment: using xscreensaver instead for now. closing the question for the meanwhile. thanks